# Sequential display of images automatically

Tags: java, android

I am using the code below to display images sequentially via button click. Now I want to display these images automatically after a particular time period. They should be displayed and change after a particular time and where the addition will be needed in the same code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static ImageView imgView;
private static Button ButtonSbm;
private int current_image_index;
int [] images={R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher1};
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    buttonClick();
}
public void buttonClick(){
imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ButtonSbm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
ButtonSbm.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            current_image_index++;
            current_image_index=current_image_index %images.length;
                    imgView.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
        }
        }

    );

  }
@Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
 }

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
 }
```

Comment: `TimerTask` will be helpful .

Comment: Where are you having difficulty? I can't find any clear questions or problem statements...

Comment: What i intend to do is i wan to display the selected images after a particular time period and they should keep changing

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use he following code

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {
    Context ctx;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    public static final String Tag="TestService";
    private long startTime= 2 * 1000;
    int index = 0;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
    public TestService() {
        super("TestService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
            countDownTimer.start();
            Looper.loop();

        }

        public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
            public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
                super(startTime, interval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                // do as per you required
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.v(Tag,"Inside OnTick()");
                    // do as per you required
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: i am new to android and java. I have type this in Main Activity

Comment: create a service and call this